# How do I plug into socket.io's built in logging system to generate my own messages?

Tags: logging, node.js, socket.io

`socket.io` seems to have a basically sensible logging system for all its internals. How do I get at that logging object myself so I can generate my own log messages at appropriate levels? It bugs me that my `console.log()` messages are un-timestamped, un-leveled, and ugly next to the `socket.io` messages. I've done a bunch of spelunking in the `socket.io` code and I'm just not savvy enough about node at this point to understand what the object hierarchies look like to know how to get at the object I want from my code.

Longer term, I'm probably going to want a more robust logging system module (with the ability to log to files, auto-rotate, manage levels on a per-module basis, custom log levels, etc.). [Winston](https://github.com/indexzero/winston) looks sensible, but can I get `socket.io` to use it, too? It'd be nice to have everything in one place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While using socket.io, I was able to plug into the existing logger module like so:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = module.exports = express.createServer(), //just creating 'app' for io
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    logger  = io.log, // access the existing logger setup in socket.io
    util    = require('util');

logger.info(util.format("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", 8003, app.settings.env));
```

[Configuring the logger](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) is also very simple:

```
io.configure('production', function(){
  io.set('log level', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using the logger middleware from [Connect](http://extjs.github.com/Connect/)? It looks like someone already created a library for what you want called [socket.IO-connect](https://github.com/bnoguchi/Socket.IO-connect). I use something similar in my [Express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware) program:

```
var connect = require('connect');

module.exports = connect.createServer(
    connect.logger({ format: ':response-time :method :url' }),
    connect.static(__dirname + '/public)
);
```

Comment: That's promising! I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow and see if it forces socket-io to route its logging messages through the connect middleware. My fallback strategy is to just set socket logging to 0 and do all my own logging with Winston. I'll lose some low-level access, but if I'm having issues at the socket level I've got larger problems that need more fine-tuned debugging anyway.